# Why does this PhantomJS process cause "Directory <x> does not exist." errors?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, phantomjs, azure-web-app-service

This is my first post, apologies if the question needs some changes. I've boiled this issue down as much as I can, but there are a lot of components here, so this post is pretty huge...

Our ASP.NET MVC site is deployed as an app service on Azure. I'm using an API controller method to produce a PDF of a page that exists on the same site. To do this, the controller creates a PhantomJS process, waits for success, and returns the contents of the file it creates. This all works fine, but afterwards several views on the site produce errors like this:

> ## Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ### *Directory 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Location' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.*
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   
>    **Exception Details:** System.Web.HttpException: Directory 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\Location' does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes.

After some time, the error changes:

> ## Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ### *The view 'LocationList' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
> ~/Views/Location/LocationList.aspx
> ~/Views/Location/LocationList.ascx
> ~/Views/Shared/LocationList.aspx
> ~/Views/Shared/LocationList.ascx
> ~/Views/Location/LocationList.cshtml
> ~/Views/Location/LocationList.vbhtml
> ~/Views/Shared/LocationList.cshtml
> ~/Views/Shared/LocationList.vbhtml*
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>    **Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'LocationList' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
> ~/Views/Location/LocationList.aspx
> ~/Views/Location/LocationList.ascx
> ~/Views/Shared/LocationList.aspx
> ~/Views/Shared/LocationList.ascx
> ~/Views/Location/LocationList.cshtml
> ~/Views/Location/LocationList.vbhtml
> ~/Views/Shared/LocationList.cshtml
> ~/Views/Shared/LocationList.vbhtml

This only applies to views that have ***not yet been compiled***, or any other file that has not previously been accessed. The only way to fix it is to manually stop and start the web application. I can confirm this doesn't happen with all processes (running "echo.exe" instead of "phantomjs.exe" doesn't cause the broken behavior).

I've looked through all the logs I can think of and haven't found anything out of the ordinary. My best guess would be that a process is being forcibly or accidentally terminated but as to what and why, I have no clue. Maybe there's some crucial log I don't know about?

Here's the relevant c# code:

```
private static async Task<int> ExecuteSimpleAsync(string workingDir, double? timeout,
    string command, params string[] parameters)
{
    var paramStr = string.Join(" ", parameters.Select(x => x == null ? "" : $"\"{x}\"").ToList());
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command, paramStr) {
        WorkingDirectory = workingDir,
        UseShellExecute  = false,                    
        CreateNoWindow   = true,
    };

    Process process = null;
    int exitCode = -1;
    using (process = new Process() { StartInfo = processInfo }) {
        process.Start();
        await process.WaitForExitAsync(timeout); // simple extension function to check for 'Process.HasExited' periodically
        exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    }
    return exitCode;
}
```

```
private static async Task<byte[]> GetFileContents(string filePath) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        bytes = new byte[file.Length];
        await file.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, (int) file.Length);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

```
public static async Task<byte[]> RenderPdfAsync(
    string cookiesB64, string localUrl, string baseFilename, double? timeout = 60)
{
    ....

    // filesPath:  (directory for temporary output)
    // timeout:    60.000 (60 seconds)
    // PhantomJSExePath: (absolute path containing 'phantomjs.exe')
    // scriptFile: "rasterize_simple.js"
    // requestUrl: "TestReport/ForUserAndTestPdf/1002/10"
    // outputFile: "phantomjs-output-<timestamp>.pdf"
    // cookiesB64: (base64-encoded authentication cookies passed to request in PhantomJS)

    var exitCode = await ExecuteSimpleAsync(filesPath, timeout, PhantomJSExePath + @"\phantomjs.exe",
    scriptFile, requestUrl, outputFile, cookiesB64);
    if (exitCode != 0)
        return null;
    return await GetFileContents(outputFile);
}
```

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("TestReport/ForUserAndTestPdf/{userId}/{testId}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ForUserAndTestPdfAsync(int userId, int testId) {
    // produce a slightly-modified version of the current URL:
    //    /TestReport/ForUserAndTest/<userid>/<testid>
    // => /TestReport/ForUserAndTestPdf/<userid>/<testid>?print=true
    var url = Request.RequestUri.GetLocalPathWithParams("print=true").Replace("ForUserAndTest", "ForUserAndTestPdf");

    // get the cookies used in the current request and convert to a base64-encoded JSON object
    var cookiesB64 = Request.GetCookiesJsonB64();
    var bytes = await PhantomJSHelpers.RenderPdfAsync(cookiesB64, url, "phantomjs-output", 60);

    var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    message.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes));
    message.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    return message;
}
```

Here's the relevant part of the "rasterize_simple.js" script used by PhantomJS, without the setup for page size, cookies, etc:

```
page.open(address, function(status) {
    page.render(outputFilename);
    phantom.exit(0);
});
```

The expected result from all this is a PDF file, which it generates, and all subsequent calls to this API method (with different parameters) work perfectly. However, the side-effect is a completely broken site :(

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the features of your ASP.NET app could not work fine in Azure WebApp, such as to fork a process to run PhantomJS and to generate a PDF file, because there are many restrictions not allow to do these, please refer to Kudu wiki page  [`Azure Web App sandbox`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) to know more.

Here is some restrictions I think you have got.

1. > PDF generation from HTML
   >   There are multiple libraries used to convert HTML to PDF. Many Windows/.NET specific versions leverage IE APIs and therefore leverage User32/GDI32 extensively. These APIs are largely blocked in the sandbox (regardless of plan) and therefore these frameworks do not work in the sandbox.
2. > Unsupported frameworks
   >   Here is a list of frameworks and scenarios that have been found to be not be usable due to one or more of the restrictions above. It's conceivable that some will be supported in the future as the sandbox evolves.
   >
   > PDF generators failing due to restriction mentioned above:
   >
   > Syncfusion
   >   Siberix
   >   Spire.PDF
   >   The following PDF generators are supported:
   >
   > SQL Reporting framework: requires the site to run in Basic or higher (note that this currently does not work in Functions apps in Consumptions mode)
   >   EVOPDF: See http://www.evopdf.com/azure-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx for vendor solution
   >   Telerik reporting: requires the site to run in Basic or higher. More info here
   >   Rotativa / wkhtmltopdf: requires the site to run in Basic or higher.
   >   NReco PdfGenerator (wkhtmltopdf): requires subscription plan Basic or higher
   >   **Known issue for all PDF generators based on wkhtmltopdf or phantomjs: custom fonts are not rendered (system-installed font is used instead) because of sandbox GDI API limitations that present even in VM-based Azure Apps plans (Basic or higher).**
   >
   > Other scenarios that are not supported:
   >
   > **PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses GDI+.**
   >
   > There are some frameworks that do not leverage User32/GDI32 extensively (wkhtmltopdf, for example) and we are working on enabling these in Basic+ the same way we enabled SQL Reporting.
3. > Local Address Requests
   >   Connection attempts to local addresses (e.g. localhost, 127.0.0.1) and the machine's own IP will fail, except if another process in the same sandbox has created a listening socket on the destination port.

The solution is to deploy your app on Azure VM, not WebApp.

Comment: Thanks - I can't upvote this answer because my reputation is too low :( But I'm marking this as correct, at least for now because the sandbox docs may have led me to a solution... Some of the issues above apply (custom font rendering doesn't work, for example), but the PDF's _are generating_ properly, the site just breaks afterwards. On a whim, I made PhantomJS run from the temp folder (via Path.GetTempPath() ) and _voila_, everything works. I suspect the files were being written in a protected folder, and the app thought this was a security violation... Would that be logged somewhere?

Comment: @Synival Except `D:\home` on Azure WebApp, writing data in other directories will cause `Permission denied` or `Access denied` error. For example, you will get `Permission denied` error when create a file via `touch` command.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my own answer because [Peter Pan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55569033/7270901) pointed me in the right direction but I found a different solution. It appears that the issue is caused by writing to a protected area in the sandbox (anything in D:\home). Running PhantomJS from `Path.GetTempPath()` and writing files there seems to fix the issue completely.

This doesn't explain *what* is happening exactly, but at least the problem is solved.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but even running PhantomJS from the temp path (D:\local\temp) and configuring it to write its temporary files there I still face the same problems after a while. I'm using NReco's PhantomJS wrapper so wondering what could be possibly different from your setup for it to work.

Comment: Ok, I found that else caused it. I was still writing in the main process, not in PhantomJS to the d:\home directory, but the weird thing is that I had been doing that for a while without issues so wondering what caused it for a single file being written there to cause the sandbox to break afterwards.

Comment: Ok, I found that one code path was still writing to the d:\home directory when I asked it to save a screenshot and passed it a full path to a folder inside the home folder. After correcting that last occurrence the problem went away!

Comment: When reviewing the [documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) on sandbox restrictions nothing like that pops up, so opened [an issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3131) against that Github repo to see if they can provide any insights.